# how to communicate between parent and child components , in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, http, angularjs-directive

***parent***

**HTML file**

```
<child [validatedMessage]="message" ></child>
```

**ts file**

```
public message = new BehaviorSubject < {} > (undefined);

public ButtonClick() {
  this.service.getDetails(Details).subscribe((result) => {
    if (result) {
      this.message.next({
        result: result
      });
    }
  })
}
```

***child***

**ts file**

```
@Input() public validatedMessage: BehaviorSubject < {} > ;

ngOnChanges() {
  this.doSomething(this.validatedMessage);
}

doSomething(validatedMessage: BehaviorSubject < {} > ) {
  alert("im in")
}
```

what is happening here is,
the alert message comes when pages load for the first time.
but I want to get an alert message when the service function API is a success.

how do I do that? I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say you're making it unnecessarily complicated. There is no need of using a `BehaviorSubject` here. You could bind a plain object to the child component. And when the reference to the variable bound changes, the `ngOnChanges` hook would be triggered.

Try the following

**Parent**

```js
public message: any;

public ButtonClick() {
  this.service.getDetails(Details).subscribe(
    (result: any) => {
      if (result) {
        this.message = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({ result: result }));
      }
    },
    (error: any) => {
      // handle error 
    }
  );
}
```

**Child**

```js
@Input() public validatedMessage: any;

ngOnChanges() {
  this.doSomething(this.validatedMessage);
}

doSomething(validatedMessage: any) {
  alert("im in")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that you've initialized `message` in your `ParentComponent` only once. And the actual reference to that `message` `BehaviorSubject` doesn't change when you pass a new value down it's `Observable` stream.

That's the reason why the `ngOnChanges` on the `ChildComponent` only get called when the App loads and then doesn't get called when a new message is pushed down the `message` `BehaviorSubject`'s `Observable` stream.

Accept the `validatedMessage` as a regular `string` in your `ChildComponent` and pass it down as an `@Input` prop to it using the `async` pipe from the template of the `ParentComponent`. Something like this in the `ParentComponent`'s template:

```
<child [validatedMessage]="message | async" ></child>
```

And in the `ChildComponent`:

```
@Input() public validatedMessage: string ;

ngOnChanges() {
  this.doSomething(this.validatedMessage);
}

doSomething(validatedMessage: string) {
  alert("im in")
}
```